# Navigation Stack configuration for static map

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I am using turtlebot3 burger with kinetic and ubuntu. I am not using laser sensor or any to build map, so i have not used gmapping. Rather i have created a static map in a image editor, and then created the corresponding .pgm and .yaml file. Now i am configuring my navigation stack. for that i have few confusions.
I have turtlebot navigation which has all its files for different models. How can i alter this for my purpose?

```
<arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
```

Also, should i exempt amcl file or do i need that?
And in last, do i need to alter .yaml files or use them as it is?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331557/navigation-stack-configuration-for-static-map/) by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-08**:
@enthusiast.australia: please mark a question as *answered* by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

We don't close questions here when they are answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you planning to localize yourself in the map? If you aren't providing scan data then you can omit the AMCL node.

The default argument is going to be whatever the environment variable TURTLEBOT3_MODEL is set. If it is not set then you can set it in your bashrc file, export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger from commandline prior to launch, or  when you launch this from the terminal you would put model:=burger after the *.launch file

---

Originally posted by [prefpkg21](https://answers.ros.org/users/40119/prefpkg21/) with karma: 61 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0